# Is there a way to make Vue variable visible inside other .js file?

Tags: javascript, vue.js

I have a File.Vue and I want to make some values visible inside my file secao.js that is being imported when the component is mounted. I tried this:

```
    mounted() {
      let self = this.Saida;
      require('../../secao.js')
      require('../../dominio.js')
      require('../../diagrama.js')
    }
```

but if gives the error '' cannot read property of undefined'' when i try to access self.attribute inside the secao.js

Comment: you should to import modules outside the `export default` object

Comment: Sorry, I did not get it. I should import what and where?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have two ways to do this.

1) Using a file to do global vars.

```js
// variables.js
export const myVar = 'This is my variable'
export const settings = {
  some: 'Settings'
}

//Other file.
import { myVar, Settings } from './variables.js'
```

2) Using States of Vuex.(Example)

```js
import Vue from 'vue'
import Vuex from 'vuex'
//PersistedState
import createPersistedState from 'vuex-persistedstate'

Vue.use(Vuex)

export default new Vuex.Store({
    strict: true,
    plugins: [
        createPersistedState()
    ],
    state:{
        token: null,
        user: null,
        isUserLoggedIn: false
    },
    mutations:{
        setToken(state, token){
            state.token = token
            if(token){
                state.isUserLoggedIn = true
            }else{
                state.isUserLoggedIn = false
            }
        },
        setUser(state, user){
            state.user = user
        }
    },
    actions:{
        setToken({commit}, token){
            commit('setToken', token)
        },
        setUser({commit}, user){
            commit('setUser', user)
        }
    }
})
```